# How can I get and use an arguments value from main in a separate file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, argparse

I am wondering how I can effectively use the arguments passed on the command line in a separate file in my project? Here's what I have so far:

### main.py

```
import argparse
from lib import topOpenPorts
# from lib import enumServices

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-t',
                        '--target',
                        help="Single IPv4 Target to Scan",
                        action="store_true",
                        default=argparse.SUPPRESS)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.target:
        topOpenPorts.TopOpenPorts.Scan(args.target)
        ## ToDo: enumServices.EnumServices.Enum(openPorts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### lib/topOpenPorts.py

```py
class TopOpenPorts:
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target

    def Scan(self, target):
        print(target)
```

When I run main.py I get this output:

```sh
# python3 main.py -t 10.10.10.10
usage: main.py [-h] [-t]
main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 10.10.10.10
```

How can I print/store the value of the -t [target] in topOpenPorts.py from main.py? Or what would be the best way of doing so if my intention is to ultimately use multiprocessing to make the project multi-threaded so I can run concurrent service scans based off of the open ports?

Comment: Your error is produced by the parser because you defined '-t' as `store_true'.

Comment: As for your Ports class, why does `Scan` take a `target` parameter?  Shouldn't it print `self.target`, using the value set when creating the object.  You need to get both the `parser` and class working right before moving on to integrating them.

Comment: In the future, please make a [mre]. This problem could be minimized down to about 5 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm a noob with python and oop so i apologize for my cruddy code and less than proper code example. I removed action="store_true" but still can't get the value of the -t arg to print out. I removed the target parameter from Scan function also, but now i'm  getting the error, str object has no attribute target.
    def Scan(self):
        print(self.target)
Once again. Sorry for my lack of python knowledge. Can someone post a working minimal example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import argparse

class TopOpenPorts:
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target

    def scan(self):
        print('target: ', self.target)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-t',
                        '--target',
                        help="Single IPv4 Target to Scan",
                        )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    if args.target:
        p = TopOpenPorts(args.target)
        p.scan()
    else:
        print('no target')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TopOpenPorts('testing ports class').scan()
    main()
```

test runs

```
2359:~/mypy$ python3 stack57538700.py 
target:  testing ports class
Namespace(target=None)
no target
2359:~/mypy$ python3 stack57538700.py -t 10.10.10.10
target:  testing ports class
Namespace(target='10.10.10.10')
target:  10.10.10.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `action="store_true"`.

`action="store_true"` makes `args.target` a boolean corresponding to whether `-t` was passed on the command line. Removing it makes `-t` require an argument. See the documentation for the [`action` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#action).

Comment: Thank you. Now i understand what the action="store_true" does. Can you post a working example of what I need to change? I removed the action="store_true" but still am getting errors. Sorry for my lack of python understanding. Trying to learn but having a hard time understanding argparse OOP implementation. Do i need to import argparse in both files?